# Does Kdb+ Support SQL-like Constraints?

Tags: database, time-series, constraints, kdb

I am wondering if there are similar concepts or functionalities available in Kdb+, like `NOT NULL`, `UNIQUE`, `CHECK`, etc.

Comment: No tables cannot be created with those rules enforced.

Comment: @rianoc thank you, do you mean that tables cannot be created with those rules ?

Comment: There is no native way to enforce those rules in the table schema. You would have to create a custom `insert` function if you wanted to do this.